# ui-select angular need a selectable option with null value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select, angular-ui-select

I'm using ui-select angular. I need an option with null value to be selected. Googled it but can't find solutions that fits.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ui-select allow-clear ng-model="hotelsCtrl.companySelectedInsert" theme="bootstrap">
                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search company in the list...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="company in hotelsCtrl.companies | filter: $select.search">
                    <span ng-bind-html="company.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
                </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select>
```

[having this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg0Hs.png)

Answer (score 0):

The straight forward way is to add and element with null value in `hotelsCtrl.companies` before setting it to `ui-select`.

something like this:

```
   {
      name:'none',
      value:null
   }
```

maybe if you want just to reset once the one of the options are selected then use backspace

here is a working example, check this out http://jsfiddle.net/Miqe/x6bqubtw

Comment: companies = [{name: 'none', value:null}];
I added this to my hotelsCtrl. But still doesn't work.

Comment: show me a sample element from `hotelsCtrl.companies` array

Comment: The array is empty. I'm getting my companies from database.

Comment: Did the same as you provided in the example, still nothing. Here's a biger chunk of code to get a better view : https://jsfiddle.net/0x71cuj7/

Comment: @Senpuki here is another example using your interface http://jsfiddle.net/Miqe/gvzmkzjb/ i've stripped out most of the variable and functions because they are dependent on other variables and `MainService` which are `undefined`

Comment: Hmm.. I did it exactly like in the example, still the option doesn't show up.. What info I should provide more, that would help you to get a better view?

Comment: pull out your browser console and paste here whats logged in there.

Comment: The console is empty I get this error, but I think it's not the case. Link: http://imgur.com/a/ovgrn